How does repeat_interval work in alertmanager?
I am having trouble making sense of some alerting behavior I'm seeing and it seems connected to repeat_interval. Can't seem to find a simple answer to my question.
Question: Will repeat_interval fire a notification again if an alert has been resolved and then retriggered?
eg. say repeat_interval is set to 24h. An alert fires and I get a notification. Then it resolved within an hour and fires again within another hour. Is it expected that I will get a notification for the 2nd trigger?

This question is similar to: Resolved Alerts resets repeat_interval in Alertmanager. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
